# Google Sheets JSON API Failed Fetch due to CORS Policy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api, cors

I am using Vue to pull data from a google sheet JSON document and keep running into the following errors, which I haven't seen before when doing the same procedure.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/11lnTz3OBSIe-60N-j3JCw09E-zJCTuMizcRa6NaJXVs/od6/public/values?alt=json%E2%80%A9' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/11lnTz3OBSIe-60N-j3JCw09E-zJCTuMizcRa6NaJXVs/od6/public/values?alt=json%E2%80%A9 net::ERR_FAILED
```

```
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Here's my Vue.js code.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        projects: []
    },
    beforeCreate: function() {
        fetch('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/11lnTz3OBSIe-60N-j3JCw09E-zJCTuMizcRa6NaJXVs/od6/public/values?alt=json ')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.projects = data
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
});
```

I tried logging the data to see what would appear in the console as well. I've read that Google may have changed their CORS policy, but I couldn't find a proper work around.

Does anyone have a proper workaround of a fix in my code that should allow me to pull the JSON API data? I eventually want to populate my HTML with refreshed data from my Google Sheet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're doing the fetch on a SSL secured url, i.e. A URL with https:// , the origin of the request should also be secured...

Google api

> https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/11lnTz3OBSIe-60N-j3JCw09E-zJCTuMizcRa6NaJXVs/od6/public/values?alt=json

The origin of the request should also be

> https://example.domain

And not

> http://example.domain

Comment: Thank you, for answering! How do I change the origin of the request? Right now, I am checking this fetch request locally.

Comment: You need to host it online, or use proxies (Which I doubt would work, cause google tech is really advanced)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up hosting it with Visual Studio Code's extension LiveServer and it seems to be working correctly .